# How to get hold of all the blobs in a Blob container which has sub directories levels(n levels)?

Tags: c#, azure, blobs

Tried using the ListBlobsSegmentedAsync method , 
but this returns only the blobs from the main parent directory level ..

But I need the entire list of blobs at one go from all the n levels of subdirectories.

```
BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.None;
int maxBlobsPerRequest = 500;
var blobOptions = new BlobRequestOptions (true );

do
 {
    var listingResult = await cbDir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, maxBlobsPerRequest, continuationToken, null, null);
    continuationToken = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
    srcBlobList.AddRange(listingResult.Results);
 } while (continuationToken != null);
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far? With actual code parts, of course.

Comment: I have jus edited my question with the code im using

Answer (score 23):

The [ListBlobsSegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) method has 2 overloads that contain the **useFlatBlobListing** argument. These overloads accept 7 or 8 arguments, and I count 6 in your code. Because there are so many arguments, you can use [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) to make the code easier to understand.

The code below has been tested successfully in .NET Core.

```
BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
do
{
    var resultSegment = await cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(
        prefix            : null,
        useFlatBlobListing: true, 
        blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None,
        maxResults        : null,
        currentToken      : blobContinuationToken,
        options           : null,
        operationContext  : null
    );

    // Get the value of the continuation token returned by the listing call.
    blobContinuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
    foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
    }
} while (blobContinuationToken != null); // Loop while the continuation token is not null.
```

This code is derived from Microsoft's [storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart) repository.

Comment: This is very helpful.

Answer (score 16):

Use this override of `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434672.aspx and make sure that you pass **`true`** for **`useFlatBlobListing`** parameter. This will list all blobs from all subdirectories.

**UPDATE**

This is the code I have used and it returns me the blobs in that subfolder and all subfolders inside that subfolder.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Code to fetch blobs from "temp" folder inside "blah" blob container.
    /// </summary>
    private static void GetFilesInSubfolder()
    {
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("blah");
        var directory = container.GetDirectoryReference("temp");
        var result = directory.ListBlobsSegmented(true, BlobListingDetails.None, 500, null, null, null);
        var blobs = result.Results;
    }
```

Comment: No gaurav,     tried it but again it gives back only the blobs from the parent directory and not from the other sub directories.

Comment: Please update your question with the code. It will be easier that way to identify the issue.

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked for me. I have updated my answer and included my code.

Comment: Tried iterating through the sub directories and achieved what i wanted. Thanks anyways Gaurav for your suggestions

Comment: But now my issue is ,its getting timeout after copying 110 MB of blob objects saying "The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.". Im unable to figure out the solution in increasing the timeout for this operation. Any help would be very helpful

Comment: @NITHESHKUMARR  do you have a complete solution now?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS  Please provide full source.  i get below info for blob  "Id = 9, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}""