# listing all blobs in container

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a function for all blobs in a container. I took the help 
[How to get hold of all the blobs in a Blob container which has sub directories levels(n levels)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395502/how-to-get-hold-of-all-the-blobs-in-a-blob-container-which-has-sub-directories-l), which seems to use an overload that doesn't exist any more. I had added default values into the additional fields `prefix` and `operationContext` :

```
static internal async Task<List<string>> ListBlobNames(string ContainerName)
{

    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    bool useFlatBlobListing = true;
    BlobListingDetails blobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.None;
    var blobOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
    CloudBlobContainer container = Container(ContainerName);
    var operationContext = new OperationContext();
    var verify = container.GetBlobReference("A_Valid_Name.jpg");
    var verify2 = container.GetBlobReference("NotAName.jpg");

    using (var a = await verify.OpenReadAsync()) ;
    //using (var a = await verify2.OpenReadAsync());   // doesn't work since it doesn't exist

    return (await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", useFlatBlobListing, blobListingDetails, null, continuationToken, blobOptions, operationContext))
            .Results.Select(s => s.Uri.LocalPath.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

The last line gave me an exception:

> StorageException: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.

I then created the `verfiy` and `verify2` variables to test if my container is valid. `verify` references a valid blob and `verify2` references an invalid blob name. Running the code with the second using statement uncommented gave me an error in the second using statement. This shows that the `verify` works and thus the container is valid.

Comment: So... are you sure you copied the code correctly? Your commented-out line does *not* refer to `verify2` - it refers to `refer2` (an undefined variable).

Comment: thanks. I changed the variable names for clarity. i forgot the code was commented when i renamed

Comment: can someone explain the downvote? anything to be added?

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to create a function for all blobs in a container.

You could leverage the Azure Storage Client Library and install the package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), then you could follow the tutorial [List blobs in pages asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-blobs-in-pages-asynchronously) to achieve your purpose. For test, I just created my .Net Core console application as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{   
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{your-storage-connection-string}");

    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    string containerName = "images";
    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    if (await container.ExistsAsync())
        await ListBlobsSegmentedInFlatListing(container);
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Your container with the name:{containerName} does not exist!!!");

    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**ListBlobsSegmentedInFlatListing:**

```
async public static Task ListBlobsSegmentedInFlatListing(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    //List blobs to the console window, with paging.
    Console.WriteLine("List blobs in pages:");

    int i = 0;
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    BlobResultSegment resultSegment = null;

    //Call ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and enumerate the result segment returned, while the continuation token is non-null.
    //When the continuation token is null, the last page has been returned and execution can exit the loop.
    do
    {
        //This overload allows control of the page size. You can return all remaining results by passing null for the maxResults parameter,
        //or by calling a different overload.
        resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 10, continuationToken, null, null);
        if (resultSegment.Results.Count<IListBlobItem>() > 0) { Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", ++i); }
        foreach (var blobItem in resultSegment.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", blobItem.StorageUri.PrimaryUri);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Get the continuation token.
        continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
}
```

**Test:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This works for me...

```
String myContainerName = "images";

CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(myContainerName);

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob; 

blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("NotAName.jpg");

bool verify2 = await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
if (!verify2)
{
 // the blob image does not exist
 // do something 
}
```

Comment: the verify part was a test to make sure the container is working. that is not where the issue was. I was trying to list the blobs